# How to maintain org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory Object

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

In application we are using OGM only and no SpringBoot or related api ,in our Controller we are using below code

```
public TopologyExtController( @Context org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService graphDb ) {

if( this.sessionFactory == null )
{
this.sessionFactory = new org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory(new org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver(graphDb), "com.demo.entity");
}
}
```

But every time the Controller will be called by request this code also call.
Can someone please tell me is this good idea to call above code every time whenever any request comes? Or We should make `SessionFactory` object `Singleton` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I cannot tell you that this is a good idea ;)
Seriously, the `SessionFactory` should just get created once. When initalizing it, it will scan all you packages for `NodeEntity`s and `RelationshipEntity`s and also create the (embedded) driver every time. Make it kind of a singleton to avoid this additional performance costs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,can you share any example if possible .

Comment: It is just creating a `static` field for the `SessionFactory`, initializing it once in the constructor, check if it is set (not null) around the initializing code. You need to do it in the constructor because you get the `GraphDatabase` object there from the database.

Comment: Thanks that we already changed ,i thought u guys followed some best way to handle such situation.